# How to load I.xlf files in Angular 4 after AoT during runtime

Tags: angular, internationalization, lazy-loading, angular-router

I have a requirement where i need to load component specific .xlf files.

My application is a Angular 4.4.5 based single page application, where i lazyload the modules only when required.

The transalations are maintained on a third-party server, where the client manages the translations. The translations are susceptible to change anytime. So, i can't bundle the translations as a part of AoT. I need to fetch the translation files everytime on page load.

Is it possible without ngx-translate? using just angular translation module?

Not using AoT for rest of the application is not a option for performance impacts :)

Comment: Well, .xlf files are not even meant to be loaded. They're meant to be used, at build time, by the AOT compiler, to generate translated bundle files.

Comment: The content i display varies based on what i receive from backend server, e.g taxes. So binding only via aot during build is not an option. I need to replace content during runtime too.

Comment: That's too vague. Edit your question, and post a concrete example of what you want to achieve. The way you internationalize an app doesn't change whether you use AOT or not, so I don't really see why you couldn't use it.